# At what time did my Windows XP machine come out of hibernation?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, hibernate, event-log

I usually look at the event log to find out at what time I switched on my computer. I look for the entry saying "The Event Log service was started". I use this to record in-out times at office. These days, I usually hibernate my computer instead of shutting it down. Now, the event log does not record an event when the machine is switched on (and rightly so).

How do I find out at what time the computer was switched on when it has booted out of hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the [**Event Log**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427) enabled,
Check the **System Log** events after a restore from hibernation.
You will find a series of events

- First will be the Event Log itself starting again
- This will be followed by System Control Manager events starting services again.

The timestamp for these events would help you identify the exact time you came out of hibernation. Once you know this pattern, it can be used any time in future.

Some notes.

1. You can reach the Event Logs through: Start ==> Administrative Tools ==> Event Viewer

   - You might want to increase the log file size if you want to retain events too far back in time (but, usually your last hibernation would not be too far back in time)
   - You can export the event log in various formats (CSV, TXT, EVT) to search through them later

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: start a command prompt and run **net statistics workstation**. The first thing returned is the start time.

Comment: He needs the time he came out of hibernation, not boot time. For that you could just use systeminfo | findstr "Up Time:"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: John T, even systeminfo gives me the time since the last full boot instead of the time since it came out of hibernation.

Comment: I know, that's what I said... If it worked for hibernation time I would have answered with it.

Answer (score -1):

there's an event from Power-Troubleshooter that says when it slept and when it woke.

"The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎10‎-‎26T16:53:59.672482300Z
Wake Time: ‎2015‎-‎11‎-‎02T06:29:32.895153200Z

Wake Source: Power Button"

Powershell - 
https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/get-the-full-reboot-history-for--troubleshooting/

C# -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106937/check-the-reason-the-computer-resumed-from-hibernation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: yeh it does - the OP is "How do I find out at what time the computer was switched on when it has booted out of hibernation?"

Comment: All you did was provide 2 links.  It is well established that an answer should be more then just links.

Comment: it's not just links, it clearly says there's an event under power-troubleshooter.

Comment: Sure;  Formatting would have been nice.