# Daily "computer on" time from Windows logfiles

Tags: windows, export, event-log, uptime

I'd like to know how long our computer is on, i.e. not in standby mode, for any given calendar day.  Is there a (free) program that extracts this information from the Windows System event log into, say, CSV format, that works on Windows XP?

Comment: Similar to http://superuser.com/questions/28567/at-what-time-did-my-windows-xp-machine-come-out-of-hibernation but for standby rather than hibernation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 choices, the first is easier but doesn't export to CSV.

**Option 1**

From the Start menu click on Run and type cmd and press enter on your keyboard.

From the Command Prompt window, type

> systeminfo | find "Up Time"

Please note, the code above is case sensitive.

**Option 2**

Also, the following powershell script does it.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Collects uptime information and exports to csv-file.
.DESCRIPTION
    Collects information about uptime and last reboot date from one or more computers and exports result to a csv-file located in logged on users "Documents" special folder. If this file already exists (the command has been run earlier the same day) it will append the new information to the same file.
.PARAMETER ComputerName
    Gets information from specified computers. Type the name of one or more computers in a comma-separated list. Default is localhost.
.PARAMETER Credential
    Specifies credentials that has permission to perform WMI-queries on remote machines. Use the object returned by the Get-Credential cmdlet as argument. For local access impersonation level 3 is always used (see Get-WMIObject). Default is current user.
.LINK
    2012 Scripting Games:
    https://2012sg.poshcode.org
.NOTES
    Author : Jesper Strandberg
    Date   : 2012-04-15
#>
function Export-Uptime {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        $Credential
    )

    begin {
        $LocalMachineAliases = $Env:COMPUTERNAME,'localhost','127.0.0.1','::1','.'
        $Result = @()
    }

    process {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            Write-Verbose "Building parameters for $Computer"
            $WmiParam = @{ Class = "Win32_OperatingSystem";
                           Property = "LastBootUpTime";
                           ComputerName = $Computer }

            if (-not ($LocalMachineAliases -contains $Computer) -and $Credential) {
                Write-Verbose "Adding credentials for $Computer"
                $WmiParam.Add("Credential", $Credential)
            }

            Write-Verbose "Accessing $Computer"
            try { $OS = Get-WmiObject @WmiParam -ErrorAction Stop }
            catch { Write-Warning $_; continue }

            Write-Verbose "Calculating uptime"
            $BootUpTime = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime)
            $Uptime = New-TimeSpan -Start $BootUpTime -End "8 am"
            if ($Uptime -lt 0) { $Uptime = New-TimeSpan }

            Write-Verbose "Building custom object"
            $Properties = @{ ComputerName = $Computer;
                             Days = $Uptime.Days;
                             Hours = $Uptime.Hours;
                             Minutes = $Uptime.Minutes;
                             Seconds = $Uptime.Seconds;
                             Date = (Get-Date -Format d -Date $BootUpTime) }
            $Result += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $Properties
        } # foreach
    } # process

    end {
        Write-Verbose "Exporting results to CSV"
        $CSV = $Result | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds,Date |
               ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'

        $OutFile = "$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Personal'))\$(Get-Date -UFormat %Y%m%d)_Uptime.csv"
        try {
            if (-not (Test-Path $OutFile)) {
                Write-Verbose "Creating $OutFile"
                $CSV | Out-File $OutFile -Encoding ASCII -ErrorAction Stop
            } else {
                Write-Verbose "Appending to $OutFile"
                $CSV | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File $OutFile -Encoding ASCII -Append -ErrorAction Stop
            }
        } # try
        catch { Write-Warning $_ }
    } # end
} # function
```

[Source](http://2012sg.poshcode.org/5492)

**EDIT**

Now, after re-reading your question, I think the answer is to use [event Log XP](http://eventlogxp.com) as lots of people say it's customizable (but I've not used it before).

About the software:
*Event Log Explorer helps you to quickly browse, find and report on problems, security warnings and all other events that are generated within Windows. Thanks to Event Log Explorer, monitoring and analysis of events recorded in Security, System, Application, Directory Service, DNS, and other logs of Microsoft Windows operating systems gets much faster and really effective.*

Comment: Option 1 (besides not working on a non-English version of Windows ;) ) only shows total uptime since last restart (e.g. 4 days...), not how much uptime there was on a particular date (e.g. on Tuesday my laptop was on and not in standby mode for 3 hours).

Comment: I'm sorry Kev, I totally didn't understand your question. Let me look again for you.

Comment: No worries.  I've installed PowerShell and am giving Option 2 a try in a minute.  The link in your comment though is for Win7, not XP.

Comment: Okay, the thing with all of these is, you're tracking shutdown events, but standby needs to be taken into account...

Comment: Also this PowerShell script is giving me errors about missing parentheses and such, which don't appear to be true, but I know nothing about PowerShell.

Comment: Well, my last suggestion is to review http://www.eventlogxp.com/ as lots of people say it's customizable but I've not used it before.

Comment: Maybe you could make a new answer with that and also how to enable the correct audit policy to log standby events, so I can +1/accept that.  Thanks!

Comment: I still don't know how to get it to log, though...looking into it but it's slow because this computer's Windows is in German and I don't understand German.  I need to know the correct policy to use to get the events to appear in the event viewer in the first place.  I tried enabling system logging using secpol.msc but it doesn't seem to catch a standby instance.

Comment: Maybe I need a separate question....

Comment: Yes, a new question would be best here